# Why does Git remember and use a conflict resolution from an aborted rebase without asking me?

Tags: git, conflict, rebase

I did a rebase on my branch `foo`

```
git rebase master
```

Did some conflict resolutions, then decided I didn't want to do it, and aborted.

```
git rebase --abort
```

All the branch log histories look normal. Now I want to start the same process again.

```
git rebase master
```

When git hits the first conflict that it hit the first time, it lists the files as in conflict just like it did before. BUT instead of marking up the conflict with `<<<<<` etc, it just shows the file in its state after I resolved the conflict the first time. This is interesting that it has this feature… but I actually want to resolve one of the conflicts differently, so I don't want it to remember and re-apply.

What exactly is going on here, and can I turn it off?

Comment: Do you have rerere enabled? http://progit.org/2010/03/08/rerere.html

Comment: ah ha-- yeah i turned that on years ago and forgot about it. looks like there isn't a flag to turn it off for a particular invocation of `git rebase`, too bad.

Comment: @admitruk not sure creating tag `rerere` is appropriate

Comment: @CharlesB: I think it is great to have rerere as a tag: recognizable and highly specific. What do you propose? git-rerere instead?

Comment: sure git-rerere is better, I was thinking that it's too specialized for creating a tag. Only my opinion though, feel free

Comment: link seems broken now. Better use official https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use rerere's "forget" function to erase a remembered conflict resolution.

Comment: Thanks… you have to use… git rerere forget [filename] _before_ you run the command above if you have rerere turned on.

Comment: For some reason forget wasn't working for me *(no idea why, it didn't report any errors)*, to forget *everything*: `rm -rf .git/rr-cache` - not ideal but can be handy, especially since I couldn't find a good way to forget-all.

Comment: @ideasman42 you should add that comment as an answer here, and I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Johann submitted removal of rr-cache as a separate answer.

Answer (score 13):

Use `git checkout --conflict=merge -- your_file` to get the version of the file with conflicts

Comment: You could also use `git checkout -m -- your_file` to have same effect, but to keep your default conflictstyle of merge intact.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `git rerere forget FILE-WITH-BAD-MERGE` to specify the file whose recorded conflict resolution should be forgotten.

If you want to forget all, you can manually remove the cache directory:

```bash
rm -rf .git/rr-cache
```