# When will Git resolve conflicts using a previous resolution and how can I disable it?

Tags: git, git-rerere

Often Git solves conflicts based on previous resolutions.

Example:

```
Auto-merging <file>
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in <file>
Resolved '<file>' using previous resolution.
Exit 1
```

1. When will Git decide to solve a conflict based on previous resolutions?
2. How can I disable the automatic solving based on previous resolutions?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://makandracards.com/makandra/21795-git-how-to-forget-a-recorded-resolution

Comment: Look into `git rerere`, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096649/why-does-git-remember-and-use-a-conflict-resolution-from-an-aborted-rebase-witho

Answer (score 2):

This is a message from “git rerere”. It is invoked manually unless it is
enabled (using Git config `rerere.enabled` set to `true`), i.e. set to
run automatically when you resolve conflicts. And since you don’t know
what it is then I must surmise that you have set it to that value.

> When will Git decide to solve a conflict based on previous
> resolutions?

git-rerere(1) will run if a previous resolution has been recorded in the
*cache*. Check if it exists with

```
ls .git/rr-cache
```

If this cache has old resolutions then you can remove them with:

```
git rerere gc
```

> How can I disable the automatic solving based on previous resolutions?

I think you can just remove the cache:

```
rm -r .git/rr-cache/
```

And maybe disable new resolution recordings by setting `rerere.enabled`
to `false`.